# How to use Angular MatTabsModule with routing in Angular 17?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-ui-router, angular-routing, angular17

I am to replicate the navigation bar as on this [website](https://slama.dev), the only difference being the whole page will not reload everytime new tab item is selected. I am using Angular MatTabsModule, which provided preserveContent and lazy loading options as well.
However, when trying to load a new component for each tab item, it does not work as expected.

I have tried using `routerLink` as well as class `Router` from `@angular/router` package, but the click on the tab item is not getting registered, and routing is not working as expected.

app.component.html:

```
<mat-tab-group>
        @for (item of tabItems; track $index) {
            <mat-tab label="{{item.label}}" [routerLink]="[item.route]"     (click)="$event.preventDefault();navigateTo(item.route)">
            </mat-tab>
        }
</mat-tab-group>
```

app.component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent {
    tabItems = [{
        label: 'Home',
        route: '/',
        }, {
        label: 'Other',
        route: '/other',
        }];

        constructor(private router: Router){}

        navigateTo(route: string){
        this.router.navigate([route]);
        }
    }
```

app.routes.ts:

```js
    export const routes: Routes = [
        { path: 'other', component: Component2 },
        { path: '', component: Component1},
        { path: '**', redirectTo: '/' }
    ];
```

app.config.ts:

```js
    export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
    providers: [provideRouter(routes)]
    };
```